# Perfomance of concatenating strings vs joining lists?

Tags: python, string, performance

I'm doing a small python exercises for fun.

I need to print something that looks like this based on some input, and some logic:

```
.P....
.I....
.D....
.Z....
BANANA
.M....
.A....
```

And right now I'm struggling a bit with constructing the strings with the dots in them.
So what I need is a function that takes a number n a number i, and a char, like this;

```
def buildstring(n,i, char):
```

And then returns a string of length n, consisiting only of dots where the i'th char is the char given.

I currently have this attempt:

```
def buildprint(n,i,char):

    start = "".join(['.']*(i))
    mid = char 
    end = "".join(['.']*(n - i-1))
    print(start+mid+end)


buildprint(10,3,"j")
```

which produces:

```
...j......
```

Which is what I want. But my solution will be graded on time, but I'm not toosure that this would be the most effecient way of concatenating the strings, since I remember something about concatenating strings often being the slow part of a program or if this would be more perfomant:

```
def buildprint(n,i,char):

    start = ['.']*(i)
    mid = [char] 
    end = ['.']*(n - i-1)
    print("".join(start+mid+end))
```

So the question is really about the way string concatenation works, vs joining lists

Comment: `'.'*i + char + '.'*(n-i-1)`

Comment: `"".join(start+mid+end)` would be even worse since you're still concatenating with `+`, but  are then re-iterating the resulting string with `join`. Your first way is much better.

For the initial part, you don't need `join` or `+` though. You can just multiply strings directly: `'.' * i`. I'd still stick with `+` for the last part though. That shouldn't matter.

Comment: `"".join(['.']*(i)` should just be `'.'*i`

Comment: and this desnt impact running time? I have once heard something about joining being much faster since it's only O(n) while concatenating is sometimes O(n*n) or something

Comment: Building up a string via repeated concatenation is slow in most languages, because Strings are typically implemented as read-only values. Each intermediate concatenation involves copying the intermediate value and adding to the end. So you get `O(N^2)` performance instead of `O(N)`. Using something like `"".join(an_array)` should be quicker, because it would have the foresight to allocate mutable storage that can be edited in-place throughout the whole process

Comment: Although, I've been told that string concatenation has actually be optimized in recent versions of Python. I remember a question about strings being mutated behind the scenes during concatenation.

Comment: "*I'm not too sure that this would be the most effecient way, or if this would be more perfomant*" - ... why ask us when you have a Python interpreter right in front of you? Try both, and find out.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I think that gets at the real question: _how to perf test small string building_ and may have the wrong duplicate (though it has some perf information and offers a wide range of (often-ancient) options)

Answer (score -1):

I would use a completly different approach using string interpolation and the
[f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

```
def buildprint(n,i,char):
    start = "".join(['.']*(i))
    mid = char
    end = "".join(['.']*(n - i-1))
    print(start+mid+end)


def build_f_string(total_char, dots, char):
    total_char -= dots + 1
    print(f'{"." * dots}{char}{"." * total_char}')

test_1 = (10, 3, "j")
buildprint(*test_1)
build_f_string(*test_1)
```

**One Liner**

```
build_f_string = lambda total_char, dots, char : print(f'{"." * dots}{char}{"." * (total_char - (dots + 1 ))}')
build_f_string(*test_1)
```

### Performance

1. Make a timer function

   ```
    from time import perf_counter
    from functools import wraps


    def timer(runs):
        def _timer(f,):
            @wraps(f)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                start = perf_counter()
                for test in range(runs):
                    res = f(*args, **kwargs)
                end = perf_counter()
                print(f'{f.__name__}: Total Time: {end - start}')
                return res

            return wrapper
        return _timer
   ```
2. Decorate our functions

   ```
        TEST_RUNS = 100_000


        @timer(runs=TEST_RUNS)
        def buildprint(n, i, char):
            start = "".join(['.'] * (i))
            mid = char
            end = "".join(['.'] * (n - i - 1))
            return start + mid + end


        @timer(runs=TEST_RUNS)
        def build_f_string(total_char, dots, char):
           return f'{"." * dots}{char}{"." * (total_char - dots + 1)}'
   ```
3. Run Tests

   ```
    test_1 = (10, 3, "j")
    buildprint(*test_1)
    build_f_string(*test_1)

    # Output

    # buildprint: Total Time: 0.06150109999999999
    # build_f_string: Total Time: 0.027191400000000004
   ```

### Going to next level

We can use Python **[Deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)**

> Deques are a generalization of stacks and queues (the name is pronounced “deck” and is short for “double-ended queue”). Deques support thread-safe, **memory efficient appends and pops from either side of the deque with approximately the same O(1)** performance in either direction.

```
def build_withdeque(n, i, char):
    hyper_list = deque([char]) # initialize the deque with the char, is in the middle already
    hyper_list.extendleft(["." for _ in range(i)]) # Add left side
    hyper_list.extend(["." for _ in range(n - i - 1)])
    return "".join(hyper_list)
```

**Running test**

```
    from collections import deque
    TEST_RUNS = 10_00_000
    
    @timer(runs=TEST_RUNS)
    def build_withdeque(n, i, char):
        hyper_list = deque([char]) # initialize the deque with the char, is in the middle already
        hyper_list.extendleft(["." for _ in range(i)]) # Add left side
        hyper_list.extend(["." for _ in range(n - i - 1)])
        return "".join(hyper_list)
    
    test_1 = (10, 3, "j")
    buildprint(*test_1)
    build_f_string(*test_1)
    build_withdeque(*test_1)
    
    # buildprint: Total Time: 0.546178
    # build_f_string: Total Time: 0.29445559999999993
    # build_withdeque: Total Time: 1.4074019
```

Still not so good..

### Pre build a list

```
@timer(runs=TEST_RUNS)
def build_list_complete(n, i, char):
    return ''.join(["." * i, char, "." * (n - i - 1)])



test_1 = (10, 3, "j")
buildprint(*test_1)
build_f_string(*test_1)
build_withdeque(*test_1)
build_list_complete(*test_1)

# buildprint: Total Time: 0.5440142
# build_f_string: Total Time: 0.3002815999999999
# build_withdeque: Total Time: 1.4215970999999998
# build_list_complete: Total Time: 0.30323829999999985
```

### Final Result

```
# TEST_RUNS = 10_00_000

test_1 = (10, 3, "j")
buildprint(*test_1)
build_f_string(*test_1)
build_withdeque(*test_1)
build_list_complete(*test_1)

# buildprint: Total Time: 0.6512364
# build_f_string: Total Time: 0.2695955000000001
# build_withdeque: Total Time: 14.0086889
# build_list_complete: Total Time: 3.049139399999998
```

### Wait no so fast

As @MisterMiyagi point out, using `return "." * i + char + ("." * (n - i + 1))` could be equivalent than using  `return f'{"." * dots}{char}{"." * (total_char - dots + 1)}'`.

However it is actually **Faster**.

Look at this:

```
def SuperHyperMegaUltraFastButBasicallyLikeFStringThatMisterMiyagiSayd(n, i, char):
    return "." * i + char + ("." * (n - i + 1))
```

Run some test with 100_00_000 repetitions.

```
@timer(runs=TEST_RUNS)
def SuperHyperMegaUltraFastButBasicallyLikeFStringThatMisterMiyagiSaid(n, i, char):
    return "." * i + char + ("." * (n - i + 1))


test_1 = (10, 3, "j")
buildprint(*test_1)
build_f_string(*test_1)
build_withdeque(*test_1)
build_list_complete(*test_1)

    
    buildprint: Total Time: 5.3067210000000005
    build_f_string: Total Time: 2.721678
    build_withdeque: Total Time: 14.302031600000001
    build_list_complete: Total Time: 3.0364287999999995        SuperHyperMegaUltraFastButBasicallyLikeFStringThatMisterMiyagiSayd: Total Time: 2.440598699999999


    buildprint: Total Time: 5.3067210000000005
    build_f_string: Total Time: 2.721678
    build_withdeque: Total Time: 14.302031600000001
    build_list_complete: Total Time: 3.0364287999999995
    SuperHyperMegaUltraFastButBasicallyLikeFStringThatMisterMiyagiSayd 

Total Time: 2.440598699999999
```

The  <strike>f-string</strike> string concatenation is the clear winner here, untill proven otherwise

Comment: The advantage of the "f-string" is because ``build_f_string`` uses a more efficient string operation, not because of the wrapping f-string. Using just ``return "." * i + char + ("." * (n - i + 1))`` in ``buildprint`` has practically identical performance than the f-string variant for me.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi  AS the test proves, f string is faster.

Comment: That's like saying walking is faster than going by car, because you had to fuel up the car first. If you let string concatenation and f-string use the same substrings, they are comparable.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi how can you let string concatenation and f-string use the same substrings? What do you mean?

Comment: As mentioned above, using ``return "." * i + char + ("." * (n - i + 1))`` is comparable to ``return f'{"." * dots}{char}{"." * (total_char - dots + 1)}'``.